# Problems with an Intent in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

```
final Button OptButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OptButton);
        OptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent OptionsSc = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
                startActivity (OptionsSc);
            }
        });
```

Eclipse keeps underlining the `new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);` part and I don't get why. Previously this call to the OptionsActivity was assigned to the hardware Search button and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `this` doesn't refer to a valid `Context`(like when you use `this` in an `Activity`), instead it refers to the anonymous inner class `OnCLickListener` class(where is the `onClick` method declare). Instead you should use:

```
Intent OptionsSc = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, OptionsActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are inside an onClickListener **class**, and you **this** refers to object of current class, here either use getApplicationcontext or YourActivityName.this

This should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Write the following code in your button click listener...

```
  Intent intent = new Intent (Main.this,Second.class);
  StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of like this,

```
 Intent OptionsSc = new Intent(YourActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class);
                startActivity (OptionsSc);
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class));
```

Comment: Problem already was explained and fixed but thank you for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that;

```
Context c= MyActivityName.this;
Intent OptionsSc = new Intent(c, OptionsActivity.class);
```